# X axis should show years for longer timeframes

Tags: feature-request, site-analytics

The following graph from `/site-analytics` covers around five years:

[image]

At first I thought the date selection didn't work, but the graph just doesn't display the year on the axis labels.

The current labels are confusing, for longer timeframes the year should be shown in the axis labels.